# How do I run an await function after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, settimeout

I need to call an await function 3 seconds after an API call has been completed using the async/await method, but have no idea how to do it.

I tried wrapping the **await** function in setTimeout() function but end up getting the error: *SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function*

```
async function tasks(
  task_id, tokenTenant
) {
  return axios({
    method: "get",
    url: `https://omitted_url/api/v1/ftth/task/${task_id}`,
    headers: {"X-Auth-Token": tokenTenant}
  }).then(res => res)
}
```

```
setTimeout(function () {
   taskResponse = await tasks(resStatus.data.task.id, tokenTenant)
   console.log(taskResponse.data)
   }, 3000)
```

The expected result in the console:

$ data:

```
   { id: '123abc456def',
     status: 'Received',
     result: null,
     tenant_id: 'john_doe_tenant_id1234',
     creation_time: '2019-04-22T13:49:01+0000' } }
```

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks for the quick response.   I did try it, but the result in the console was: *undefined".
It seems like when a setTimeout() function is used, the "res" data from the *tasks()* function is not passed down into the variable, **taskResponse**

Comment: `.then(res => res)` - what's this NOP for?

Comment: please don't post multi-line code in a comment .... if you need to use setTimeout to wait for the response to finish, then you're *doing something wrong™* -

Comment: @JaromandaX, ok multiline removed.  
I know I am doing something wrong. That's why I am requesting assistance.  

Comment: but, without the setTimeout, the expected result seems to be along the lines of the result you're getting - so, why the delay?

Comment: by the way, since `function tasks` returns a Promise, and never has to use `await` there's no need to tag it `async`

Comment: ... *(but it's a great hint for further developers usign that function that it does return a Promise and needs to be awaited)*

Comment: The API I am making calls to configures network devices, such as switches and routers.  There is a delay from when the config is pushed to the device to when the config is applied successfully.  The API thus provide a *task" response with an ID.  After 3 seconds, I can use the ID to check on the status of the config push.

Comment: Then delaying the call is reasonable and JaromandaX' advice does not apply in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Awesome!  Thanks to @JonasWilms and @SelmiKarim for pointing me in the right direction.

I managed to get the setTimeout() working by change my original block of code from:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   taskResponse = await tasks(resStatus.data.task.id, tokenTenant)
   console.log(taskResponse.data)
   }, 3000)
```

to

```
const promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    resolve(tasks(resStatus.data.task.id, tokenTenant))
  }, 3000);
})

respo = await promise1.then(resp => resp)
```

Not sure if this is best practise but it is working for me.

Thanks so much, everyone!

Comment: You still don't need the `.then(resp => resp)`. That doesn't do anything, so just remove it.

Comment: `respo = await promise1;`

Answer (score 1):

While that could easily be fixed by using an `async` function just as the error suggests:

```
 setTimeout(async function () {
```

it might be benefitial to promisify `setTimeout` as:

```
 const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

because then it can be written as:

```
 (async function /*³*/ delayTask() {
    await delay(3000);
    /*¹*/const taskResponse = await tasks(resStatus.data.task.id, tokenTenant); /*²*/
    console.log(taskResponse.data);
})();
```

Notes:

¹: Always declare variables!

²: Never trust ASI to rescue you, use Semicolons!

³: Function names in IIFEs help you during debugging (but they are optional).

Comment: Thanks, will quickly try and provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

you must use await function inside of async.

The async and await keywords are absent from our Promise code. We use them to configure asynchronous functions that call our promise and wait for it to complete, like this:

```
var callMyPromise = async () => {
    var result = await (myPromise());
    return result;
};
```

Comment: Your right.  It was merely a typo in my last comment.  I have updated to reflect how it currently is in my code.

respo = await promise1.then(resp => resp)